# How to type ` on Mac keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro

I searched my US American MacBook keyboard and I did not find symbol of "`" (grave accent). Did I miss it?

Comment: What country keyboard are you using?  On the US keyboard it is in the top left corner to the left of the 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the US keyboard it is in the top left corner to the left of the 1.

You'll see it just under the tilde sign (~) in the top left of the keyboard.